# Statistical test or distance metric for comparing different distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test, matlab, distance

I want to compare the distributions of two different groups to determine if they are statistically different. Here is an example:

```
x = [839,1186,458,465,146,79,247,379,626,64];
y = [493,252,168,162,94,93,87,77,59,44];
```

where such vectors represent the observed frequencies for ten different categories.

To perform the comparison, I used the Chi-square goodness-of-fit test in MATLAB:

```
[h, p] = chi2gof(bins, 'Ctrs', bins, 'Frequency', x, 'Expected', y)
```

The test results showed that `h = 1` and `p = 0`, indicating that the two distributions are significantly different.

However, I also computed some additional metrics to quantify the degree of dissimilarity between the distributions. The cosine similarity returns a high value (0.87), coherently with the Jensen–Shannon divergence which returns a small value (0.06). Both the two metrics agree that the two distributions are quite similar.

So, my question is: how can I interpret the discrepancy between the output of the Chi-square test and the output of the two metrics?

Comment: Look up the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "statistically different"?  Frequently, when people believe they need a test of distributions, they are really interested only in one property of the distributions, such as their means, and comparing the distributions themselves is a poor procedure in that context.  Indeed, exactly how do these lists of numbers represent "distributions"? The references to cosine similarity and chi-squared testing suggest you are *not* considering them as datasets, but perhaps as counts or something else.

Comment: Maybe the distribution allows for ten different outcomes and the numbers say how often these were observed? In that case the sample sizes are large, so even small discrepancies between the distributions will lead the chi squared to reject. The distributions are obviously not identical, hence the chi squared result. They are to some extent similar, having higher values in the first entries, which might explain the cosine result. I don't know much about the behaviour/scaling of Jensen-Shannon, so I'm not sure this actually is a very small value (if correct).

Comment: @whuber Indeed, those numbers are counts. I used them when running the chi test, while I considered the normalized frequencies (i.e. the probabilities) for calculating the distance metrics.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I see your point, but it is still not clear to me which kind of conclusion I can say about those two frequency vectors.

Comment: @Firebug the ks test returns the same result of the chi test

Comment: @ALESSANDROGNUTTI You could improve the question saying explicitly in the question that the vectors give observed frequencies for ten different values/categories. (It may make a bit of a difference whether these are ten numerical, ordinal or just categorical values, so it could be helpful to say what the values actually are.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is still not clear to me which kind of conclusion I can say about those two frequency vectors

There is very strong evidence that the two distributions are not the same (chi squared test). That said, they have a bit in common in that they have their highest probabilities in somewhat similar places (one could have distributions on these 10 categories/values that are much more different).